# Replace old Objective-c library by new Swift one in several apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I have an old library in objective C, developped by several people following (one stop and the next continue the project...).
This library is used in several applications, most of them developped in objective C.
I want to add new features in this app, but the code is not maintainable actually (no tests, no comment, etc...).

My main idea was to rebuild a framework or library in Swift. I have the business requirement but I'm not comfortable with objective c.

Am I going to have compatibility problems if I want to use my new swift library in "old" objective C application, or It could be great If I don't change the API?

Could it be transparent for the client who have his own application and have to use the new library now?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you keep the interface the same and mark all previously public methods/properties as `@objc`, there should be no breaking changes to the API of the library and hence all consumers should be able to continue using it without any changes on their side.

However, be aware that having to mark all methods as `@objc` will limit your ability to use the full extent of Swift, since some features of Swift are not available in Obj-C and hence if you want your types/functions to be available in Obj-C, you cannot use such features (i.e. you cannot use tuples in function signatures or add methods to your enums).